# C# Unity > accessing GameObject in Parent Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine

This question is probably more Unity than C# specific. Trying to pass a reference of the current GameObject to the Parent Class.

Getting the following error

***Internal_CreateGameObject can only be called from the main thread.***

This is the relevant code in my child class

```
 public override void Start()
    {
       init("green", gameObject);
    }

    public override void init(string classRef, GameObject go)
    {
        base.init(classRef, go);
        Debug.Log("init " + classRef);
    }
```

And in my Parent class

```
virtual public void init(string classRef, GameObject go)
    {
        _wallRef = classRef;

        _go = go;
    }
```

What's wrong with my logic? Is it even necessary to pass a reference of the current gameObject to the Parent class with inheritance in Unity(Monobehaviour)?

Comment: Are you sure that "can only be called from the main thread." is not related to your problem? You are not showing anything related to threading in your post...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the full code,but is your parent class inheriting from the main class ?

Comment: In C# Unity you normally inherit from MonoBehaviour , although you can create standalone classes that are totally separate from the editor.

Comment: Ehh,you have child class,and you have the parent class
child class must inherit from parent class,right ?

Comment: my issue has nothing to do with inheritance but rather the inability to access the main thread from a Timer handler. Am posting another question.

Comment: If u want to use overrided function you must inherite from the class where is used the "virtual" word